# removing class - unable to target correct class

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a created a Jquery add and remove class function. Which will be used for multiple items throughout my webpage [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/7owwvecd/21/).

Thus far i have created a addclass button which works well, however i seem to be unsuccessful with the remove class function. Below is a snippet of my code

```
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
             $(this).closest('.card')
                .addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
                 $(this).removeClass('flipped');
                })
            });
            return false;
```

thanks

Comment: So whats the issue? The card flips back on `mouseleave` , that's what your code intends to do. Or do you want to flip back with the button only?

Comment: flip back with the button only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use toggleClass

```
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

EDIT :  [See fiddle with multiple elements](http://jsfiddle.net/7owwvecd/22/)

**EDIT 2**: So, to flip back other cards when clicking one, you have to remove class of all .flipped (except current clicked), and then, flip your card, like this:

```
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $card = $(this).closest('.card');
    $('.flipped').not($card).removeClass('flipped');
    $card.toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7owwvecd/24/)

Comment: This doesn't not work well with multiple elements ….

Comment: it does not remove the class of the pervious element if the second element is active

Comment: I don't get it, I edited your fiddle, the elements work fine independently. You want to flip them all at once ?

Comment: no. I want them to flip individually. when you Flip element 1 element flips back… vice versa

Comment: yes, but that's not what i am trying to achieve. I want it so when if you flip one element the other element flips back

Answer (score 0):

Try: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/7owwvecd/20/)

```js
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store value of `$(this)` in a variable and use it.

```
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var elem = $(this);
            elem.closest('.card')
                .addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
                 elem.removeClass('flipped');
                })
            });
            return false; });
```